# Do i need DNS if i just plan to use my api server with ip address

Tags: server, apache2, dns, webserver, virtualhost

I am planning to use my api server without domain name.
I am just planning to use `http://ip_address/user/ , http://ip_address/user/update/1232`

Do i need DNS?
Do i need any special config file in apache?
Additionally how do i test apache benchmark for this ip_address?

```
ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://ip_address is not working
```

Comment: Did you create at least the default virtual host listening on all IPs on port 80?

Comment: when i enter the ip address, i can see the api output in json format

Comment: What is the output of `ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://ip_address/`?

Comment: it shows all the possible options to use ab. ab: invalid URL
Usage: ab [options] [http[s]://]hostname[:port]/path

Comment: With or without the trailing slash after the IP?

Comment: Awesome. After adding a trailing slash, it is working. Is there any problem using an api server without any domain name? You asked me about virtual host. Do i need to create a default virtual host?

Comment: I cannot see there being any problem with using the API without a domain, as you will not need your users to remember the server / its name, because it will only be accessed by your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need DNS or a valid domain name pointing to your server. 
You will be able to use the API without any problems, even without it.
Apart from a very basic apache configuration (a vhost listening on all IPs on port 80 / 443 for SSL) you will not need any special config.

Your ab command is not working because you are missing the trailing slash, so instead of
`ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://ip_address`
use
`ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://ip_address/`